# Add image column into an existing mysql table?

Tags: mysql, database, addition

I want to add a new column called image in an existing `mysql` table.

The type is **BLOB**, the attributes are BINARY and NO NULL

What code should I use in PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: this is better,you don't save image in db and save image path

Answer (score 2):

In PhpMyAdmin you can use the table editor to add a new column from clicking on the structure of a table.

The mysql command instead, would be:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD image MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL
```

MEDIUMBLOB has a maximum size of 16MB, use LONGBLOB (up to 4GB) for anything bigger

If you have problems uploading BLOBs, check the value of max_allowed_packet http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use BLOBs for saving images.

Save the files somewhere on your webserver for example .../htdocs/images/picture.jpg (assuming you use xampp).
then create a simple Column in you Database for Strings of the image names. To show you why i will use PHP.
in your .../htdocs/index.php

you can then do something like the following:

```
<?php
//enter you PhpMyAdmin details here.
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db("mydbname")) {
    echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT imageName
        FROM   MyTable
        ;

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

// While a row of data exists, put that row in $row as an associative array
// Note: If you're expecting just one row, no need to use a loop
// Note: If you put extract($row); inside the following loop, you'll
//       then create $userid, $fullname, and $userstatus
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>
    <img src="images/<?=$row["userid"]?> <!-- this will get repeted for all the rows in you database -->
    <?php
}

mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

this is where i got the sample code from:
[PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)
i just modified it a bit .. but the php documentation is great btw.

Comment: You have a typo in the definition of `$sql` you forgot the end quote. Also you shouldn't use `mysql_*` i would recommend you `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. And in your SQL statement you never selected `userid`

Comment: @Rizier123 jajajaja uf SO schribsch wider, chamer jetzt nurno so mit dir kommuniziere?